# UDF functions not working using java JDBC

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, hadoop, hive, emr

I am using EMR cluster and added step config which picks my UDF jar and creates function . EMR cluster is getting created and i am able to use those UDF functions from hive CLI. But, I am getting error while executing the same query using java jdbc. can anyone please help me out?

I am creating permanent function -
  CREATE FUNCTION add AS 'brickhouse.udf.collect.CombineUDF'

Error is org.apache.hive.service.cli.HiveSQLException: Error while compiling statement: FAILED: SemanticException [Error 10011]: Invalid function add

Answer (score 0):

I think i am close to solution. The solution is to restart EMR cluster. Does anyone have any idea how to restart EMR services using java SDK.

For proof , i tried the same udf function using CLI , and it works smooth. Then i restarted hive-server service using command 
sudo stop hive-server2
sudo start hive-server2

now once again i tried running my code using java jdbc , and it works this time .

Going further , we can created a step to stop/start hive . its working for me .